# choosing regularization constant in compressive sensing

Tags: learning-theory, compressed-sensing

Given a compressive sensing formulation,

$$\left\| {Ax - b} \right\|_2^2 + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_1}$$

And given curves

(a) $\left\| {Ax - b} \right\|_2^2$ plotted against $\log \left( \mu  \right)$

(b) $\left\| {Ax - b} \right\|_2^2$ plotted against ${\left\| x \right\|_0}$

Without any cross validation, is there any types of heuristics about which fit should i choose ?

I suspect choosing fits according to minimizing $\left\| {Ax - b} \right\|_2^2 \cdot {\left\| x \right\|_0}$ would be a good heuristic. Is it true?

Comment: What is $||.||_0$ ?

Comment: @JeanDuchon: number of non-zero components (sparsity regularization if you will)

Comment: I am not aware of any results, but have you looked into continuation methods? Homotopy methods? Bi-level optimization? Hyperparameter optimization? 

This problem is interesting to a lot of people, and it doesn't seem to attract a lot of answers: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182063/how-to-calculate-the-regularization-parameter-in-linear-regression/